# high load low cpu low iowait, why?

Tags: performance, centos, cpu-usage, iowait, cpu-load

[image]

[image][image]

Look at the those peaks in the first graph, which factor can cause this?

cpu 24X6

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff going on in any general purpose computer. When I performance profiled apps in a former life, I saw this all the time and factored it out.

It's caused by a whole host of sources: Processor dealing with interrupts, some disk maintenance routine, file system clean up, completely useless background apps that have been installed unknown to you as automatically launched services, etc.

Your plot of idle time is a little disconcerting. It is awfully low. What apps do you have running taking up all that processing? Also, if your memory is low, say because you have 20 or 30 browser tabs/windows open, your CPU load will go through the roof due to all that page and context swapping.

Comment: thanks for your tips first. My question's context is a reading web application server in production environment, and my raid disks lacks of writing cache,would this factor causes this peaks?but iowait is constantly low.And My Memory is enough, no need for swapping.